# Calling asynctask from GCMBaseIntentService?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Hello I have this code in my GCMIntenBaseIntenService

```
 @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        AsyncTask taskDoStuff= new AsyncTask (context);
        taskDoStuff.execute();

    }
```

my AsyncTask is looking like:

```
public class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {


Context mContext;



    public AsyncTask(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;

}
```

when I call my asynctask from my main ACTIVITY directly it works - AsyncTask runs and does its job...
But when I try to call asynctask from GCMBaseIntentService it does not does it job - surely because of wrong context...

How can I solve that?

used: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ as basic

EDIT:

I did some change, now it works in the background , but app crashes:

In my MainActivity i set

```
public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MainActivity.mContext;
    }
```

in onCreate:

```
MainActivity.mContext = MainActivity.this;
```

in gcm onMessag()

```
AsyncTask taskDoStuff = new AsyncTask(MainActivity.getAppContext());
        taskDoStuff.execute();
```

Comment: Dont know if it will fix, but you should rename it, dont call it AsyncTask

Comment: it's already renamed, just renamed it for my post here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GCMBaseIntentService` extends [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which per the documentation:

> the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Which means that as soon as `onMessage` completes, the service is killed.

As `onMessage()` is already on a worker thread, you can do your background work directly in `onMessage()` rather than needing an `AsyncTask` at all.

If you really, really need to reuse an AsyncTask, you can use `taskDoStuff.get()` instead of `taskDoStuff.execute()` to retrieve the results using the current thread.

Comment: Is it not possible to call asynctask from gcmbase..?

Comment: Added a note on using `taskDoStuff.get()` instead of `taskDoStuff.execute()`

Comment: Going to try.. Just a second

Comment: Unfortunately 'error appears' isn't quite enough information to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Unhandled exception type ExecutionException appears when i replace execute with get

Comment: So what happens when you handle that exception?

Comment: what do you mean with to handle it

Comment: Add a try/catch around the statement http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm

Comment: Ok im gonna try it..  Maybe another point : the Problem is not really calling of asynctask.. The Problem is that I need context in my asynctask for a Dialog that should appear, but it cant due to some wrong context

Comment: i did it, but it does nothing^^ nothing happens

Comment: Yes, showing a dialog from a service is an entirely different question than running an AsyncTask from a service and have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: I have a New Problem Now.. I am using a activity instead asynctask Now but when i Create activity with İntent whenever Massage arrives the activity appears which contains a asynctask to Do stuff in background Hmm..

Comment: Is there any way I can run the created activity in background or iş there any other way to get My asynctask run called by My gcmintenservice